# Can integers be defined in the first-order theory of the rationals?

Tags: model-theory, rational-numbers, first-order-logic

Can integers be defined in the first-order theory of the rationals with addition, multiplication, and order?

Comment: Order is unnecessary, it is definable from addition and multiplication.

Comment: True, I and a friend had just worked this out. Somehow I found it simpler to state it this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It's a much celebrated theorem of Julia Robinson.

> Julia Robinson, **[Definability and Decision Problems in Arithmetic](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2266510)**. *The Journal of Symbolic Logic*, Vol. **14**, No. 2 (Jun., 1949) , pp. 98-114