# Small elementary extensions of $\langle\mathbb Q, 0,1,+,-,×,<\rangle$?

Tags: model-theory

Is it possibile to describe the elementary extensions of $\mathbb Q$, in the language of ordered rings, that have no infinitesimals?  ( Subquestion: can they all be embedded in $\mathbb R$? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes: $\mathbb{Q}$ is the only elementary extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that has no infinitesimals.

First, it's a famous [theorem of Julia Robinson](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/670623/7062) that $\mathbb{N}$ is definable in $\mathbb{Q}$. Let's say $\varphi(x)$ is the formula defining $\mathbb{N}$.

Second, there is a definable function $f\colon (n,m)\mapsto \frac{n}{m}$, defined by $f(n,m) = q \iff q\cdot m = n$ which is surjective from the pairs of positive natural numbers to the positive rational numbers.

Now let $\mathbb{Q}\prec \mathcal{Q}$ be a proper elementary extension. Since $a\mapsto -a$ is a bijection between the positive rational numbers and the negative rational numbers, $\mathcal{Q}$ contains new positive rational numbers which are not in $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $f$ is surjective onto the positive rational numbers, this implies that $\mathcal{Q}$ also contains new "natural numbers": $\varphi(\mathbb{Q})\subsetneq \varphi(\mathcal{Q})$. Now for any standard natural number $n$, the theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ asserts that there are exactly $n$ elements less than $n$ which satisfy $\varphi(x)$. So a new element of $\varphi(\mathcal{Q})$ cannot be less than $n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus $\mathcal{Q}$ contains an infinite element $\omega$ satisfying $\varphi(x)$, and hence an infinitesimal element: the multiplicative inverse of $\omega$.

The answer to your subquestion is then (trivially) yes. But it's also not hard to show that every (not necessarily elementary) ordered ring extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ which has no infinitesimals can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$: just note that every element fills a proper Dedekind cut in $\mathbb{Q}$, and map it to the corresponding real number.

Comment: Thank you, your argument is convincing. Still, I am confused: why it is not possibile to construct a model containing $\mathbb Q\cup \{\sqrt 2\}$ and omitting $\{n<x:n\in\mathbb N\}$?

Comment: @PrimoPetri The theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ says $\forall x\, x^2\neq 2$. So no elementary extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ contains $\sqrt{2}$! Of course, by compactness you can find an model containing an element $x$ which sits in the Dedekind cut of $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. But then $x^2$ must be either infinitesimally greater than or infinitesimally smaller than $2$, and in either case we get an infinitesimal in the model. A more interesting question is why you can't construct a model containing $\mathbb{Q}\cup \{\pi\}$ and omitting $\{n<x\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$...

Comment: ... and one answer is obtained via the argument I gave: The theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ says that every element is a ratio of natural numbers. $\pi$ is not the ratio of any two standard natural numbers, so a model which contains $\pi$ must also contain non-standard natural numbers. From the point of view of the omitting types theorem, note that if $\varphi(x)$ defines $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, then the formula $\psi(x): x\neq 0\land  \varphi(x)\land \exists y (\varphi(y)\land x = \pi y)$ is consistent and implies $n < x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so you can't omit this partial type.

Comment: thank you, now I'm less confused.